TensorExpand with Koszul signs
I am very new in Mathematica, and I am struggling computing the multiplication of tensor products with Koszul signs.
Let $V$ be a vector space and $a,b,c,d \in V$. In usual situations, the product of $a \otimes b$ and $c \otimes d$ is given componentwise; i.e. $(a \otimes b)(c \otimes d) = ac \otimes bd$. In mathematica, I can use TensorExpand as below to do the symbolic computation.
(KroneckerProduct[a, b]) . (KroneckerProduct[c, d]) // TensorExpand

However, in the graded case with Koszul signs (thus $V$ is a graded vector space), the result becomes $(a \otimes b)(c \otimes d) = (-1)^{deg(b)\deg(c)}ac \otimes bd$ where $deg$ is the degree of the element. (In this case we assume that $a,b,c,d$ are homogeneous.) If the elements $a,b,c,d$ are not homogeneous (thus sums of homogeneous elements of different degrees), I have no idea how to do this in Mathematica. Can anyone help this?

I'm not very familiar with tensor products; I only have a basic understanding. Let's consider a simple example where elements a,b,c,dcan either be homogeneous or sums of homogeneous components:
(* Define a function to compute the degree of an element *)
degree[x_] := 0; (* Define your degree function here *)

(* Graded tensor product function *)
gradedTensorProduct[a_, b_, c_, d_] := Module[{sign},
  sign = (-1)^((degree[b]) * (degree[c]));
  sign * KroneckerProduct[a, c] ⊗ KroneckerProduct[b, d]
]

(* Example usage *)
a = a0 + a1; (* Example of a sum of homogeneous elements *)
b = b0 + b1;
c = c0 + c1;
d = d0 + d1;

result = gradedTensorProduct[a, b, c, d];
result // TensorExpand



Dear Zeraoulia, thanks for the answer. I tried this on Mathematica but it seems like gradedTensorProduct does not work well for general elements since the degree function is not well-defined in these cases. Still, I really appreciate your help.
